# jq Handling JSON Array as input to parse the elements of the JSON array within a while loop

Tags: arrays, json, bash, jq

Looked at many posts on a similar topic but I am doing something wrong as I keep getting "jq: error: Could not open file" or "Invalid numeric literal".
I am trying to pass a JSON array as a string value through jq to a while loop and read the elements of the JSON array within the loop.
Basic bash script works with <<< ${PRESET_ARR}) but doesn't work when calling from a nodejs app.

Trying to call this bash script from a nodejs app. I can get just the batch script to work with <<< ${PRESET_ARR})
But calling the batch script from nodejs causes "parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1".

Changed to use <<< echo "${PRESET_ARR}") and calling from nodejs causes "jq: error: Could not open file"

My bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

PRESET_ARR=$1
echo "PRESET_ARR=${PRESET_ARR}"
#PRESET_ARR='[{"resolution":"2160*2160","bitrate":60M,"framerate":60},{"resolution":"1350*1350","bitrate":"30M","framerate":60}]'
#./batch.sh '[{"resolution":"2160*2160","bitrate":"60M","framerate":60},{"resolution":"1350*1350","bitrate":"30M","framerate":60}]'
#echo "${PRESET_ARR}" | jq -r '.[] | (.resolution, .bitrate, .framerate)' |

while IFS= read  resolution &&
      IFS= read  bitrate &&
      IFS= read  framerate;
#for row in $(echo "${PRESET_ARR}" | jq -r '.[] | (.resolution, .bitrate, .framerate)');
do

    echo "resolution=$resolution"
    echo "bitrate=$bitrate"
    echo "framerate=$framerate"

done < <(jq -r '.[] | (.resolution, .bitrate, .framerate)' <<< echo "${PRESET_ARR}")
#done < <(jq -r '.[] | (".resolution", ".bitrate", ".framerate")' <<< ${PRESET_ARR})
```

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your script is too encrusted to debug it effectively.  Anyway, the following is a tweaked extract from your script, and does work nicely:

```
#!/bin/bash

PRESET_ARR='[{"resolution":"2160*2160","bitrate":"60M","framerate":60},{"resolution":"1350*1350","bitrate":"30M","framerate":60}]'

while IFS= read  resolution &&
      IFS= read  bitrate &&
      IFS= read  framerate
do

    echo "resolution=$resolution"
    echo "bitrate=$bitrate"
    echo "framerate=$framerate"

done < <(jq -r '.[] | (.resolution, .bitrate, .framerate)' <<< "${PRESET_ARR}")
```

Perhaps the problem you were facing can be resolved by replacing
`PRESET_ARR=$1` by `PRESET_ARR="$1"`.

Comment: Thx for your reply.The batch script works for me with the commented line as you show. It doesn't work when calling the batch script from the nodejs app.The comments are there to show various options I have tried based on other solutions on stackoverflow.

Comment: @peat The nodejs script is the same but i get the presetJsonArr comes from the DB. I get the "jq eror: Could not open file [ { resolution: 1560*1560, bitrate: 30M, framerate: 30 } ]: No such file or directory\n". Tried changing the bash script to use <<< "${PRESET_ARR}") as well as <<< echo "${PRESET_ARR}") as the JSON array input. It still doesn't work. I also used  PRESET_ARR="$6". Error that shows:  stderr: ++ jq -r '.[] | (.resolution, .bitrate, .framerate)' '[ { resolution: 1560*1560, bitrate: 30M, framerate: 30 } ]'\n",

Comment: Changing to use I/P with a -n :
done < <(jq -r '.[] | (.resolution, .bitrate, .framerate)' <<<  echo -n "${PRESET_ARR}")

gives an error:
"stderr: ++ jq -r '.[] | (.resolution, .bitrate, .framerate)' -n '[ { resolution: 1560*1560, bitrate: 30M, framerate: 30 } ]'\n"
stderr: jq: error (at <unknown>): Cannot iterate over null (null)\n"